# When loading data from php onto a page that automatically refreshes is not rememering that a row was hidden by the client device

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have an annoying issue where once the client device has hidden data using:

```
echo "function hideReq";
echo $row['requestID'];
echo "() {";
echo "var x = document.getElementById('play";
echo $row['requestID'];
echo "');";
echo "if (x.style.display === 'none') {";
echo "x.style.display = 'block';";
echo "} else {";
echo "x.style.display = 'none';";
echo "}";
```

The code above adds the script dynamically through the same PHP that adds the ID's data so that each ID's data can be affected by the script itself.

It is unset once the data has been refreshed through php using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function getData(){
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'locationData.php',
success: function(data){
$('#dataoutput').html(data);
}
});
}
getData();
setInterval(function () {
getData(); 
}, 120000);  // it will refresh your data every 3 mins
});
```

The code above gets the data from an external PHP document that is added to a div on the page on a 3-minute cooldown.

To clarify, the code works as expected. Once the refresh cooldown has been reached the data loads as it is meant to. However, the hidden rows are once again visible.

I just need to know how to either;

1. Make it so that the data requests only the data with the IDs that are not already on the device so that it can remember the hidden rows
2. Add a method that will still refresh all of the data and also keep the rows hidden.
   Whichever is easier.

Comment: How do things get hidden in the first place? http is stateless but you can store some page state either on server or in each user's localStorage and use script to do the visibility filtering

Comment: You didn't ask, but trying to manage javascript from PHP echo statements, especially when they're broken up like this is a nightmare. No reason why you can't have that javascript function available to your pages either inline or in an external .js file. Just supply the arguments to the function.